# Modifying command globally from within command

Tags: macros, luatex, environment-variables

I've seen a couple of somewhat similar questions, but none with similar construct or -- I'll be honest -- none with answers I've been able to understand well enough to adapt to my situation.

The context is that I have a long document where some figures are repeated often, but with different labels and captions.

I've made one "main command" (`\pptFigure`) which is used in the text. This is a wrapper creating a figure. One of three variables given to `\pptFigure` is to a "sub command" (in the minimal working example `\pptOne` and `\pptTwo`) which contains the actual content of the figure.

My problem is that I would like the subcommands to redefine a command (or variable) which the main command would use. In the MMWE it's called `\pptTitle`.

`\pptTitle` is used both within the sub-command and in the main-command, but it's content is only correct in the sub-command. *In other words, I'd need the sub-command to redefine it globally.*

I'm sure some concoction of `\expandafter` and/or `\makeatletter` + `\makeatother` might be a solution, but so far I haven't been able to figure out how.

Minimal (updated) working example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \providecommand{\pptTitle}{empty}

    \newcommand{\pptFigure}[3]{%
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \fbox{%
                \hspace{5mm}

                \begin{minipage}[h]{0.85\textwidth}
                    \vspace{5mm}
                    #1
                    \vspace{5mm}
                \end{minipage}
                \hspace{5mm}
            }
            \caption{#2: \pptTitle}\label{#3}
        \end{figure}%
    }

    \newcommand{\pptOne}{%
        \gdef\pptTitle{Title one}
        \begin{center}
            {\large \pptTitle}
        \end{center}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item Point
            \item Point
        \end{itemize}
    }

    \newcommand{\pptTwo}{%
        \gdef\pptTitle{Title two}
        \begin{center}
            {\large \pptTitle}
        \end{center}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item Point
            \item Point
        \end{itemize}
    }

    \begin{document}

    First figure.\pptFigure{\pptOne}{captionPart1}{label1}

    Second figure.\pptFigure{\pptTwo}{captionPart1}{label2} 

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Adapted the MWE (now working as intended) using the second solution (`\gdef`) provided by @christian-hupfer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an boxing and grouping issue -- Outside of the `minipage`, `\pptTitle` is still empty, but expanding `pptTitle` first (after using a copy with `\let` and redefining `\pptTitle` to be an `\gdef` (expanded definition) will work outside. Even a `\global\renewcommand` wouldn't work here.

`minipage` is a special `parbox` and as such it's a box, i.e. the `\(re)newcommand` definition get's lost inside the box, but `\gdef` or `\xdef` will survive.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \providecommand{\pptTitle}{empty}



    \newcommand{\pptFigure}[3]{%
      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \fbox{%
          \hspace{5mm}

          \begin{minipage}[h]{0.85\textwidth}
            \vspace{5mm}
            #1%
            \let\innerpptTitle\pptTitle
            \gdef\pptTitle{\innerpptTitle}
            \vspace{5mm}
          \end{minipage}
          \hspace{5mm}
        }
        \caption{#2: \pptTitle}\label{#3}
      \end{figure}%
    }

    \newcommand{\pptOne}{%
      \renewcommand{\pptTitle}{Title one}

      \begin{center}
        {\large \pptTitle}
      \end{center}

      \begin{itemize}
      \item Point
      \item Point
      \end{itemize}
    }

    \newcommand{\pptTwo}{%
      \renewcommand{\pptTitle}{Title two}
      \begin{center}
        {\large \pptTitle}
      \end{center}

      \begin{itemize}
      \item Point
      \item Point
      \end{itemize}
    }

    \begin{document}

    First figure.\pptFigure{\pptOne}{captionPart1}{label1}

    Second figure.\pptFigure{\pptTwo}{captionPart1}{label2} 

    \end{document}
```

**Here's a small example that shows the boxing issue here**

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\foo}{This is foo}


\begin{document}
\foo

\parbox{10cm}{\global\renewcommand{\foo}{This is bar}\foo}

\foo



\parbox{10cm}{\gdef\foo{This is bar inside with gdef}\foo}

\foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `\global`... Did not work --- but `\gdef` did!

Comment: `\global\renewcommand` never works